# Custom order by two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

There's complex mysqli query which returns an array of products. I need to sort the result in a specific way: the products must be sorted by price (asc or desc), and then all the products with quantity=0 must be placed in the end of the result array. So the returned array is:
    
    
    product_id          name      price       quantity
    
    
    0001               product1     100            3
    
    
    0005               product2    105           2
    
    
    0003              product3    110          10
    
    
    0002              product4     115            4
    
    
    0008              product5     120           2
    
    
    0004              product6    105           0
    
    
    0005               product2    135           0

Doing ORDER BY quantity DESC, price doesn't help because all products become ordered by quantity before being ordered by price. Otherwise, ordering BY price, quantity DESC places all the products with quantity=0 in the middle of the table. Need some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
ORDER BY quantity = 0, price
```

`quantity = 0` will be `1` for all the items with zero quanity, it will be `0` for everything else.

Comment: Great solution, I would have used CASE WHEN but this is much more elegant and concise.